# Problema con metodo en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un método definido en mi modelo `Affiliate` de la siguiente manera:

```
def is_a_valid_email?
   (email =~ /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/)
end
```

Al ejecutarlo en mi *rails console* me tira el siguiente error: (aclaro que en mi variable `a` tengo guardado los datos de un afiliado especifico que yo busqué con un `find_by_id`):

```
2.6.3 :068 > a.email.is_a_valid_email?
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):68
    1: from (irb):68:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `is_a_valid_email?' for "fr an. cof .. er7@gmail.com":String)
```

Codigo modelo affiliate:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: affiliates
#
#  id                :bigint           not null, primary key
#  code              :string           not null
#  start_at          :date             not null
#  active            :boolean          default(TRUE), not null
#  expiration_at     :date
#  person_id         :bigint           not null
#  id_persona        :integer
#  confirmed_at      :datetime
#  confirmation_code :string
#  user_id           :bigint
#  affiliate_type_id :bigint           not null
#  card_number       :string
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  email             :string
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_affiliates_on_affiliate_type_id  (affiliate_type_id)
#  index_affiliates_on_code               (code) UNIQUE
#  index_affiliates_on_person_id          (person_id)
#  index_affiliates_on_user_id            (user_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (affiliate_type_id => affiliate_types.id)
#  fk_rails_...  (person_id => people.id)
#  fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)
#

class Affiliate < ApplicationRecord

  # == Associations
  belongs_to :person, inverse_of: :affiliate
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'AffiliateType', foreign_key: :affiliate_type_id

  has_many :affiliate_plans
  has_many :plans, through: :affiliate_plans
  has_many :authorisations
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, through: :relationships, source: :child

  has_one :inverse_relationship, foreign_key: :child_id, class_name: 'Relationship'
  has_one :parent, through: :inverse_relationship

  # == Validations
  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true, null: false, length: {minimum:3}
  validates :person, presence: true
  validates :person_id, uniqueness: true, null: false
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :confirmation_code, length: { is: 3 }, presence: true
  #validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  #validates :card_number, length: { is: 3 }, if: 'card_number.present?'

  # == Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, :reject_if => :all_blank

  # => scopes
  scope :actives, -> { where( active: true ) }
  scope :inactives, -> { where("active = ? or active is null", false) }
  scope :confirmed, -> { where("confirmed_at is not null") }
  scope :unconfirmed, -> { where("confirmed_at is null") }

  # == Constants
  RELATIONSHIPS = [
    'NO ESPECIFICADO',
    'ESPOSO/A',
    'HIJO/A',
    'PADRE',
    'MADRE',
    'NIETO/A',
    'SOBRINO/A',
    'HIJO/A DE CONYUGE'
  ]

  # == Class Methods
  def self.without_relationship
    Affiliate.where("affiliates.id not in
                       (SELECT parent_id FROM relationships
                                UNION
                        SELECT child_id FROM relationships)")
  end

  # == Instance Methods
  def is_a_valid_email?(email)
    (email =~ /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/)
    #email =~ Devise.email_regexp
  end

  def code_fullname
    "#{code} - #{person.try(:fullname)}"
  end

  def fullname
    person.try(:fullname)
  end

  def practice_used_odont_month
    #cantidad de practicas odontologicas consumidas en el mes 
     sum_dentistry(Date.new(Time.now.year,Time.now.month,1))
   end 

   def practices_used(practice, from=1.year.ago)
     sum_practices(practice.id, from)
   end

  def confirmed?
    confirmed_at
  end

  def actived?
    active
  end

  def confirm!(code)
    self.update_column(:confirmed_at, Time.now) if code.try(:to_s) == self.confirmation_code
  end

  def email_affiliate
    if category.code[0] == 'T' then
      email
    else
      parent.email unless parent.blank?  
    end 
  end

  private

  def sum_practices(practice_id, from)
    self.authorisations.consumed.joins(:items).where("authorisations.created_at > (?)", from).where("authorisation_practices.practice_id = ?", practice_id).sum(:quantity)
  end

  def sum_dentistry(from)
    pract = Practice.no_count_odont.pluck("id")
    self.authorisations.consumed.joins(:items).where("authorisations.created_at > (?) and authorisations.affiliate_id = ?", from, id).where("authorisation_practices.practice_id IN (?)", pract).sum(:quantity) 
  end  
end
```

Comment: el modelo esta instanciado ?

Answer (score 0):

El método se debe llamar en la instancia de `Affiliate`, pero lo estás llamando en el atributo `email` (que es un *String*); así debería quedar:

```
a.is_a_valid_email?
```

Comment: Si, lo he probado de esa manera y me tira el siguiente error: NoMethodError (undefined method `is_a_valid_email?' for #<Affiliate:0x00007fd94fbc65f8>)

Comment: @francofernandez ¿Podrías mostrar el código del modelo `Affiliate`?

Comment: Si, alli te lo adjunte a la pregunta.

Comment: @francofernandez Se muestra el código del método pero no del modelo completo, ¿podrías incluir el código completo del modelo?

Comment: Ahora si, disculpa

Comment: El comportamiento es extraño, no debería mostrarse ese mensaje; sin embargo hay un error en tu método pues, no necesita parámetros; intenta sin ellos: `def is_a_valid_email?`

Comment: Si en realidad cuando copie el codigo del modelo habia modificado justo y agregado el parametro, pero de todas maneras sin el me da el mismo error.